# Java, (Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I use Eclipse using Java,

What'S Wrong With This Code ??

I get this error `"Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete "`

```
{
  public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu paramAnonymous2ContextMenu, View paramAnonymous2View, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo paramAnonymous2ContextMenuInfo)
      {
          ((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)paramAnonymous2ContextMenuInfo);//**Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete**
                        paramAnonymous2ContextMenu.add(0, 0, 0, "Delete");
      }
});
```

Comment: What is this line supposed to do?

Comment: deleting the position,based on gps location...

Answer (score 0):

this isn't valid statement, you might be trying to assign it to something

```
((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)paramAnonymous2ContextMenuInfo);
```

like

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo someRef = ((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)paramAnonymous2ContextMenuInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

`((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)paramAnonymous2ContextMenuInfo)` isn't a valid statement; it doesn't do anything.

I suspect you meant to do this:

```
((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)paramAnonymous2ContextMenuInfo).add(0, 0, 0, "Delete");
```

Comment: The method add(int, int, int, String) is undefined for the type AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo

Comment: That means you're calling a method that doesn't exist. Quite a different problem...